# Get style attribute value from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have HTML like below. On clicking div `.swatch-option` i am reading the style attribute of `no-display` class then adding the class for the `.normal-price` div.

style attribute of `no-display` class is giving me value as as `inline`, but the value actually is `none`.

How to get that value here? Can anyone look into this and update me please.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.swatch-option').on("click", function() {
    var styleval = $('.no-display').css("display");
    if (styleval == 'none') {
      $('.normal-price').addClass('swatch-price');
    } else {
      $('.normal-price').removeClass('swatch-price');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="normal-price">Test</span>
<div class="swatch-option" aria-checked="true">Eng</div>
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display" style="display: inline;"></span>
<span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee"></span>
<span class="price-label">Regular Price</span>
<span id="old-price-5429" data-price-amount="2" data-price-type="oldPrice" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">£2.00</span></span>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: try `$('.no-display').is(':hidden')` insted

Comment: Or just `toggleClass()`

Comment: the value actually is `none`. I dont see the code that change `$('.no-display').css("display")`

Comment: `This is always giving the value as inline, but the value actually is none.` ? No, in the code you shared the value is `inline`.

Comment: I think you have to check the display property for var styleval = $('.normal-price').css("display"); instead of no-display class

Comment: @MihaiT, no on clicking it the style of display property is toggling, so i am reading it

Comment: where are you doing that toggle of display ? i cannot see it in your code

Comment: @MihaiT, that is happening dynamically, i am using magento framework. so first i am reading style value and doing these changes

Comment: You have a css somewhere `.normal-price.swatch-price ~ .no-display { display: none } ` . ?  Or how does magento change the display property on an element when you add a class on another element ? The code must be somewhere. CSS or javascript. It's not ' magic ' Anyway. Long story short. use what the first comment says

Comment: @MihaiT, not cleared with ur comment, yes on clicking style of no-display class changes from inline to none

Comment: My question is HOW ?

Comment: @MihaiT, already some javascript written from inbuild library files, so i am altering the functionality like this